# php get info from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So by the way i want to get the nickname of member by faction id. but its not printing name. whats wrong with my code? when i print $nickname its not giving me anything too.

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
session_start();

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT nickname FROM members WHERE fraction='3'");

print($result->num_rows);
?>
  <div class="form">

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#lspd">LS-PD</a></li>
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#ballas">BALLAS</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">    
        <div id="ballas">   
          <h1>Ballas</h1>

          <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
          {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
              echo "<p class='monitoring-name'>" . $row['nickname'] . "</p><br>";
            }
          } 
          ?>
          </form>
        </div>  
      </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
```

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: How can i check error log?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: The error logs are on your web server.

Comment: Ah, no theres not any error. i printed num_rows as you see and its returning 1.

Comment: Is it possible you meant "WHERE faction = '3'" instead of "WHERE fraction = '3'"?

Comment: So add the error reporting I suggested and silly errors like that will get reported to you

Comment: Look for any typo as well

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. Add a check to make sure that your query is right, so if it is then it will run the code, else it will generate an error:

```
$query = "SELECT nickname FROM members WHERE fraction = 3";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<p class='monitoring-name'>" . $row['nickname'] . "</p><br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No results found"; // pretty clear?
    }
}
else
{
    // if there's an error with your query it will display this message:
    echo "There was a problem with your query";
}
```